# Integrate Lan drivers for windows server 2012 r2 for Intel NUC with MDT

Tags: deployment, intel, windows-server-2012-r2, mdt

I am trying to install windows 2012 r2 via MDT to NUC . However I am having problems with the network driver. Intel did not write support for windows server into the driver. I have found posts on the internet on how to modify the .inf file and to disable driver signing. But this is a manual process and defeats the object of mdt.
this link on how to hack manually

http://foxdeploy.com/2013/09/12/hacking-an-intel-network-card-to-work-on-server-2012-r2/

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure which version of the NUC you're using, but I'm running the D54250WYK in Windows Server 2012 R2 flawlessly:

1. Right click the network card in Device Manager and go to "Update Driver"
2. Click "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
3. Select "Intel" under manufacturer and "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I218-LM" from the list. (If the driver isn't in the list, try downloading and installing the latest Windows 8.1 x64 NUC network drivers.

Looking at the spec sheets, I'm guessing the I218-V (on the NUC) and I218-LM are the exact same hardware with a different device ID. The I218-V's SKU is specifically to disable Windows Server support.

Note: You can probably follow the same instructions if your NUC has the I217-V Network Adapter (I217-V installed as I217-LM) or some other integrated network adapter following the same naming schema.

Answer (score 0):

I installed windows 10 on my NUC to see what drivers were used then selected them on windows 2012 r2 and it worked just fine. In my case the NUC7i7BNH uses the Intel Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V